# My profile picture disappeared

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-picture

I manage my Stack Overflow identity via Facebook. This morning, when I came online, my beautiful photo was replaced by the empty silhouette.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with Facebook's new data sharing policy, or a bug on SO's side which has corrupted the image data?

Comment: My money's on Facebook making *some* tweak to its API that this is referencing...

Comment: MSE duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309231/what-happen-on-stack-overflows-facebook-image

Comment: Same problem... Just wanted to open a question - and then found this one. So writing here as a comment. 
Im my specific case - the image is only disappeared from stackoverflow and here, but in [fitness.stackexchange](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/18789/nikita-kurtin) community  the image still exists

Comment: @NikitaKurtin Blame caching for that one; iirc the pictures are cached somewhere.

Comment: Of course it comes form facebook, you know they are currently reinforcing their security. Just add your picture manually using SO

Comment: I was wondering, is this happening nowdays as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming that SO was using the public API to retrieve your picture then [Retrieving Default Image All Url Profile Picture from Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49917726/2191572) explains that an access token is now required. Likely in response to the recent senate hearing.

Not much that we (users) can do at this point except wait for Facebook to finish their API changes and wait for SO to react to those changes.